# useEffect hook not triggered when state is updated somewhere else

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, use-effect

I`m having some problems trying to listen to state changes in this application. Basically I was expecting a useEffect hook to be fired after some state changed, but nothing at all is happening.

This is what I got

**index.jsx**

```
// this is a simplification.
// I actually have a react-router-dom's Router wrapping everything 
// and App is a Switch with multiple Route components
ReactDOM.render(
<Provider>
    <App>
</Provider>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**useSession.jsx**

```
export const useSession = () => {

  const [session, setSession] = useState(null)

  const login = useCallback(() => {
     // do something
     setSession(newSession)
  })

  return {
    session,
    setSession,
    login
  }
}
```

**Provider.jsx**

```
const { session } = useSession();

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('Print this')
}, [session])

// more code ...
```

**App.jsx**

```
export function Login() {
    const { login } = useSession();
    return <button type="button" onClick={() => { login() }}>Login</button>
}
```

Well I have this Parent component Provider watching the session state, but when it is updated the useEffect of the provider is never called.

The `useEffect` is fired only if the `setSession` is called in the same hook/method. For example, if I import the `setSession` in the `Provider` and use it there, the `useEffect` will be fired; Or if I add a `useEffect` in the `useSession` method, it is gonna be fired when `login` updates the state.

The callback of `useEffect` is called but only once, when the component is mounted, but not when the state is changed.

How can I achieve this behavior? Having the `Provider`'s `useEffect` fired whenever `session` is updated?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Trying to wrap my head around why the login function is decorated with a `useCallback` hook... without a dependency array. Without I am sure it isn't really memoizing the login callback. I don't think that is the issue, but it is odd. What else are you expecting to trigger changes to `session` in `useSession` *other than the setter*?

Comment: Agree with @DrewReese. It might have to be with useCallback. Try using a regular function. If that does't help, a codesandbox will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is just a bit of misunderstanding of how custom hooks work.Every instance of the component has its own state. Let me just show a simple example illustrating this.

```js
function App () {
  return (
    <div>
      <ComponentA/>
      <ComponentB/>
      <ComponentC/>
      <ComponentD/>
    </div>
  )
}

function useCounter() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);

  function increment() {
    setCounter(counter+1)
  }

  return {
    increment, counter, setCounter
  }
}

function ComponentA() {
  const { counter, increment }= useCounter()
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={()=>increment()}>Button A</button>
      ComponentA Counter: {counter}
    </div>
  )
}

function ComponentB() {
  const { counter, increment }= useCounter()
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={()=>increment()}>Button B</button>
      ComponentB Counter: {counter}
    </div>
  )
}

function ComponentC() {
  const { counter }= useCounter();
  return (
    <div>
      ComponentC Counter: {counter}
    </div>
  )
}

function ComponentD() {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = React.UseState(false);
  const { counter }= useCounter();

  React.useEffect(() => {
     setInterval(()=>{
       setToggle(prev => !prev);
     }, 1000)
  })

  return (
    <div>
      ComponentD Counter: {counter}
    </div>
  )
}
```

From the above code if you can see that incrementing count by clicking `Button A`will not affect the count instance of `ComponentB`.This is because ***every instance of the component has its own state***. You can also see that clicking either buttons won't trigger `ComponentC` to rerender since they don't share the same instance. Even if i trigger rerender every one second like in Component D thus invoking `useCounter` the counter in `ComponentD` remains 0.

**Solution**
However there are multiple ways of making components share/listen to same state changes

1. You can shift all your state i.e [session state] to the `Provider` component and make it visible to other components by passing it via props.
2. You can move state to a global container ***Redux*** or simply use ***Context Api + UseReducer Hook*** [here is an example](https://swizec.com/blog/usereducer-usecontext-for-easy-global-state-without-libraries/swizec/9182)

But since you are dealing with auth and session management, I suggest you persist the session state in local storage or session storage, and retrieve it whenever you need it. Hope that helped

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is another interesting reading about this subject https://medium.com/@akrush95/global-cached-state-in-react-using-hooks-context-and-local-storage-166eacf8ab46

Everytime I called `useSession` I was recreating the hooks. I thought that somehow it was preserving the values internally. But it wasn't, so every call is a new state